# Using repo on drive shared by Windows 7 and VirtualBox Ubuntu 16 VM

Tags: git, virtualbox, repo

I have a Windows 7 PC. I am using VirtualBox 5.1.18 to run an Ubuntu 16.04 VM on the PC. I have a drive shared between the two operating systems. I need to use repo to manage my git repositories. When, on the shared drive, I do

```
repo init -u <MyManifest> -b <revision> --no-repo-verify --repo-url=git://android-git/git-repo
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tools/fly/.repo/repo/main.py", line 531, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/tools/fly/.repo/repo/main.py", line 507, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/home/tools/fly/.repo/repo/main.py", line 180, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/tools/fly/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 390, in Execute
    self._SyncManifest(opt)
  File "/home/tools/fly/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 163, in _SyncManifest
    m._InitGitDir(mirror_git=mirrored_manifest_git)
  File "/home/tools/fly/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2196, in _InitGitDir
    self._UpdateHooks()
  File "/home/tools/fly/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2215, in _UpdateHooks
    self._InitHooks()
  File "/home/tools/fly/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2243, in _InitHooks
    os.symlink(os.path.relpath(stock_hook, os.path.dirname(dst)), dst)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system
```

I believe this is because VirtualBox does not support symlinks for a drive shared with Windows.

Is there any way to work around this?

TIA, K

Comment: Why would you share a git between linux and windows ? git is intended to be cloned on both machines, not to be shared by removable drive

Comment: I would suggest that you create a bare repo in the shared drive, which two separate clones (one for each OS) use as a remote.

Comment: So one reason is that PyCharm keeps dying in the VM so I'm editing the code using Windows PyCharm and then executing it in Ubuntu.